# Why is the data not getting appended to the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code is:

```
<table id="listDB">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Shop</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Price Based On</th>
        <th>MRP</th>
        <th>Seller's Price</th>
        <th>Last Updated On</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery Code is :

```
$.each(json.listArr.category, function() {
    console.log(this.category);
    $("#listDB").append($('<tr>')).append($('<td>', {
        class   : "catHead",
        colspan : 11,
        text    : this.category
    }));
});
```

The console contains the output of `console.log(this.category);` listed as:

[image: Console.lot Output]

So, why isn't the data thus acquired getting appended to the table? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** This syntax `$("#listDB").append($('<tr>'))` returns you a `table` and not a `tr`

[image]

So technically you are then trying to append a `td` to the `table` which is **invalid**. ie: Your current code is equivalent to

```
$("#listDB").append($('<td>', {
```

**Solution:** You need to append `td` to `tr` right now your code appends to `table`

Use this syntax

```
$("#listDB").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>', {
// -------------------------^^ Notice I removed a ")"
```

So your script must look like

```
$("#listDB").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>', {
        class   : "catHead",
        colspan : 11,
        text    : this.category
    })));  // added one more ")"
```

To avoid confusion, lets try using variable.

```
 var $tr = $('<tr>');
 $tr.append($('<td>', {
            class   : "catHead",
            colspan : 11,
            text    : this.category
        }));
 $("#listDB").append($tr);
```

Comment: Are you missing a `;` at the end of the first append?

Comment: @SomenathSinha updated, Also it works with out that.. But its a good practice to always end the line with `;` .. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Can I write (using the same pattern as yours):

var $tr = $('<tr>');
     var $td = $('<td>', {
      class   : "catHead",
      colspan : 11,
      text    : this.category
     });
     $("#listDB").append($tr).append($td);

Comment: P.S. You're also missing a `)` at the end of the first append. Also, the above code (that I commented) or your code didn't work. The table is still empty. Any ideas why?

Comment: @SomenathSinha  you cannot do `$("#listDB").append($tr).append($td);` it must be `$("#listDB").append($tr.append($td));` .. **NOTE** : `$tr.append($td)` must come inside `$("#listDB").append()`

Comment: Done. But the table is still empty. Any ideas why?

The output of running your code in the terminal is http://i.imgur.com/pFE1irD.png

Isn't that the original problem you told me about?

Comment: @SomenathSinha its not an issue.. Can you tell me what you get in your `$td` ?

Comment: Solved it. Turns out I'm trying to access category.category which is why the operation was failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130876/discussion-between-somenath-sinha-and-rajshekar-reddy).